# How to use the screens based on the device size

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I have 3 Login screens:

- one is for large and extra-large devices(Example: Laptops, desktops, etc).
- the second one is for medium devices(Example: Tablets, Ipads).
- the third one is for small and extra-small devices(Examples: Mobiles).

Based on the device I should display the login screen If I open my web application on laptop I should display login screen-1, on Ipad I should display login screen-2, on mobile I should display login screen-3.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mobile query for this

Typescript :

1. Declare:

   `mobileQuery: MediaQueryList;`

   `private _mobileQueryListener: () => void;`
2. In the constructor injection add :

   `media: MediaMatcher,`

   `changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef`
3. In constructor code add :

   `this.mobileQuery = media.matchMedia('(max-width: 700px)');`

   `this._mobileQueryListener = () => changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();`

   `this.mobileQuery.addListener(this._mobileQueryListener);`

HTML :

`<div *ngIf="mobileQuery.matches">`
`code for mobile view`
`</div>`

`<div *ngIf="!mobileQuery.matches">`
`code for desktop view`
`</div>`